# Accessing Jdatabase via JavaScript Or Passing PHP varibles to JavaScript

Tags: mysql, javascript, jdatabase

I want to use this [SVG Pie Chart](http://codepen.io/ivanrafael/pen/exsaq) on my Joomla site but the problem is I need to access data from `Jdatabase` and feed it to its **index.js**

```
$(function(){
  $("#pieChart").drawPieChart([
    { title: "Cash",              value : 40,  color: "#2C3E50" },
    { title: "Fixed Interest",    value:  8,   color: "#fe4400" },
    { title: "Property",          value:  24,   color: "#018ab6" },
    { title: "Australian shares", value : 16,   color: "#fff100" },
    { title: "Intl. shares",      value : 12,   color: "#D7DADB" }
  ]);
});
```

I need **variables** having Jdatabase data instead of `40`,`8`,`24`,`16`,`12` in the above code. Do I need to pass variable from `PHP module` to `index.js` file or directly access Jdatabase via `index.js`? In any case, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, simply put the jQuery code you're using to call the Pie Chart (NOT the entire Pie Chart library) inside the module's `default.php`.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $foo1 = 40;
    $foo2 = 8;
    $foo3 = 24;
    $foo4 = 16;
    $foo5 = 12;
?>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#pieChart").drawPieChart([
    { title: "Cash",              value : <?php echo $foo1; ?>,   color: "#2C3E50" },
    { title: "Fixed Interest",    value:  <?php echo $foo2; ?>,   color: "#fe4400" },
    { title: "Property",          value:  <?php echo $foo3; ?>,   color: "#018ab6" },
    { title: "Australian shares", value : <?php echo $foo4; ?>,   color: "#fff100" },
    { title: "Intl. shares",      value : <?php echo $foo5; ?>,   color: "#D7DADB" }
  ]);
});
</script>
```

Or you could use `addScriptDeclaration()`, like so:

```
<?php
    $foo1 = 40;
    $foo2 = 8;
    $foo3 = 24;
    $foo4 = 16;
    $foo5 = 12;

    JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
        $(function(){
           $("#pieChart").drawPieChart([
             { title: "Cash",              value : ' . $foo1 . ',   color: "#2C3E50" },
             { title: "Fixed Interest",    value : ' . $foo2 . ',   color: "#fe4400" },
             { title: "Property",          value : ' . $foo3 . ',   color: "#018ab6" },
             { title: "Australian shares", value : ' . $foo4 . ',   color: "#fff100" },
             { title: "Intl. shares",      value : ' . $foo5 . ',   color: "#D7DADB" }
          ]);
        });
    ');
?>
```

Comment: You never disappoint me. Worked perfectly. I have one more query, I need to display multiple pie charts with different variables. Can I somehow use this JS inside a PHP loop?

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop "`foreach ($results as $chart) { ... }`". Start trying to write the code based on this and if you run into any issues, ask a new question, with the code you've already got.

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize your coding by passing the exact data (json object) that `drawPieChart()` is asking for in a single variable.

In side of your loop:

```
// perform sql query that generates the following formatted multi-row resultset:
$resultset = [
    ["title" => "Cash", "value" => 40,  "color" => "#2C3E50"],
    ["title" => "Fixed Interest", "value" => 8,  "color" => "#FE4400"],
    ["title" => "Property", "value" => 24,  "color" => "#018AB6"],
    ["title" => "Australian shares", "value" => 16,  "color" => "#FFF100"],
    ["title" => "Intl. shares", "value" => 12,  "color" => "#D7DADB"]
];
$json = json_encode($resultset);  // repackage the resultset
$piechart_id = "piechart1";    // dynamically generate this value in loop
$js[] = "$('#{$piechart_id}').drawPieChart({$json})";
```

Then after your loop is finished iterating, write the multiple `drawPieChart()` calls in a single block of code so that you aren't making seperate declarations for each call.

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(function($) {
        ' . implode("\n", $js) . '
    }
');
```

I haven't tested the above snippets, but the logic should be sound.